# jquery Animate each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this list and i want to animate through each list item, basically have a cascading effect of each item moving a few centimeters upwards.

I have created this code in order to achieve this but it seems it's animating through the whole list rather than individual list item.

JS - jquery

```
$("#energy_guide ul").animate({"top" : "+=20px"}, "fast");
```

and the HTML

```
<ul class="guide-block-list us-list" id="energy_guide">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Do you guys have any advice regarding how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Select `li`s using `$("ul#energy_guide li")`.

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you want.

```
var delay_time = 0;
$("#energy_guide ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay_time).animate({"top" : "+=20px"}, "fast");
    delay_time += 200;
});
```

It loops through each of the `li`'s. The first `li` will have a delay of 0, the second a delay of 200 milliseconds, the third a delay of 400 milliseconds and so on. So it will animate them at different times, right after each other. Feel free to change the delay times and increment from 200 to something else if you want it to go quicker/slower.